# Running Davinci Resolve with AMD GPU

Tags: arch-linux, amd-graphics, mesa, opencl

I want to run Davinci Resolve on my Arch Linux system with a AMD 7900 XTX GPU. Currently Resolve does not even start (process exits immediately after start). Here are the outputs:

```
$ ./resolve
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level= 1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level= 1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level= 1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode= 0, Level= 0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0
PnlMsgActionStringAdapter Already in Table: Code= 615e, Mode= 0, Level= 0, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
18.6.4.0006 Linux/Clang x86_64
Main thread starts: 37006000
0x7efd37006000 | Undefined | INFO | 2023-12-09 05:35:11,591 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x7efd37006000 | Undefined | INFO | 2023-12-09 05:35:11,591 | Loaded log config from /home/vankurt/.local/share/DaVinciResolve/configs/log-conf.xml
0x7efd37006000 | Undefined | INFO | 2023-12-09 05:35:11,591 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also tried davinci-resolve-checker, to see if I have the correct Open CL and GPU packages installed. Here's what it says:

```
DaVinci Resolve checker 5.2.5
Installed DaVinci Resolve package: davinci-resolve-studio 18.6.4-1
Chassis type: desktop
Installed OpenCL drivers:
opencl-rusticl-mesa 1:23.2.1-2
rocm-opencl-runtime 5.7.1-1
Presented GPUs:
Navi 31 [Radeon RX 7900 XT/7900 XTX] (kernel driver in use: amdgpu)
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon RX 7900 XTX (gfx1100, LLVM 16.0.6, DRM 3.54, 6.6.4-arch1-1)
clinfo detected platforms and devices:
AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing (roc) (number of devices: 1)
AMD Radeon RX 7900 XTX
rusticl (number of devices: 0)

All seems good. You should be able to run DaVinci Resolve successfully.
```

Has anyone been able to run Davinci Resolve with a AMD 7900 XTX? Are there any other packages I need to install? Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the LInux kernel version. Davinci resolve and derivative programs that use ROCM will not run if they use (I haven't figured out what it is) certain methods of accessing the GPU.

How to fix it?

Install an LTS kernel if you are unable to knock down a particular version of the Linux kernel.

Everything will work on kernel versions **before 6.5.x**. **Kernel versions 6.6.x will not work**. I also checked that this problem still exists on 6.7.2.

Enter the command `sudo dmesg`. It will show a log like this:

```
amdgpu 0000:0d:00.0: amdgpu: bo 000000006ed69fd0 va 0x0800000000-0x08000001ff conflict with 0x0800000000-0x0800000002
```

A link to the same error cases:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/3037

P.S. Davinci Resolve is running on **kernel 6.6.14-1-lts**. I am using archlinux